# How to pray Salatul Duha?

Tags: salat, sunnah, nafl

How and when do i pray Salatul Duha (Sunrise Prayer).

Answer (score 2):

Salat ad-Doha is an optional prayer which has according madhhabs a level between mandub and sunnah muakkadah (based on ahadith such as [this](https://sunnah.com/bukhari/19/56) of abu Hurrairah and [this](https://sunnah.com/tirmidhi/3/23) on the authority of abu ad-Darda' and abu Dharr).

**The time for this optional prayer** is after sunrise and before noon (a possible evidence for the starting time is [this hadith](https://sunnah.com/tirmidhi/6/43) from Jami'a at-Tirmdihi and the timing is limited by [this sahih hadith](https://sunnah.com/muslim/6/357)).
The most preferred time for it is after the half of the time between sunrise and noon.

> The scholars defined this as being when one quarter of the day has passed, i.e., halfway between sunrise and Zuhr prayer.
>   See al-Majmoo’ by al-Nawawi, 4/36;  al-Mawsoo’ah al-Fiqhiyyah, 27/224 . (Source islamqa #[22389](https://islamqa.info/en/22389))

**About the amount of raka'a's** there's a consensus on the minimum (two raka'a's, based on narration such as [this](https://sunnah.com/muslim/6/101) in sahih Muslim) while the there's a dispute on the maximum amount.
The Maliki's, Shafi'is and Hanbalis say it is eight raka'a based on ahadith such as [here](https://sunnah.com/muslim/6/97) and [here](https://sunnah.com/muslim/6/98) in sahih Muslim if one performed more those would be considered as nafl (optional). However some Shafi'is said it was tweleve due to a hadith compiled by imam al-Bayhaqi. The hanafis said the maximum is sixteen raka'a. Othe scholars among them imam at-Tabari said there's no limitation.

**As for how to pray it** the majority of scholars say one may pray it in two by two sets (as described [here](https://sunnah.com/urn/1313830) in the narration compiled by ibn Majah)and it is also permissible to pray it as four by four sets. ...

Additional references in Arabic [Article](http://mawdoo3.com/%D9%83%D9%8A%D9%81_%D9%88%D9%85%D8%AA%D9%89_%D8%AA%D8%B5%D9%84%D9%89_%D8%B5%D9%84%D8%A7%D8%A9_%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%B6%D8%AD%D9%89) and this fatwa on islamweb #[28916](http://fatwa.islamweb.net/fatwa/index.php?page=showfatwa&Option=FatwaId&Id=28916)

Answer (score 0):

Assalamu'Alaykum O Rahmatullah O Barokatuh! 
The question should be what time to pray salatul Duha. 
Us after sun rise for example in London is at 07:30 after that time you can start to pray 2 rajah or 4. You can pray by two rakah like the Farj prayer or by 4 rakah like Duhur Asr Isha. 
All the Salah are the same there is no difference. So you pray in the same way you pray Fard payer. 
Assalamu'Alaykum O Rahmatullah O Barokatuh! 
Take care.