# What is Salat ul Awabeen? Is it supported by Sahih Hadiths?

Tags: salat, hadith-interpretation, nafl

I recently came across the below message:

> Generally the six rakats after the Maghrib salah is called the Salatul
>   Awabeen.  However, according to the Sahih and authentic ahadith,
>   Salatul Awabeen has been used to described Salatul Duha.
>
> Saaiduna Zaid Ibn Arqam Radiallahu Anhu said “The Prophet of Allah
>   Sallallahu Alahi Wasalam came out to the people of Quba while they
>   were praying and said, “Salatul Awabeen is the time when the young
>   camels sit (i.e. they sit because of the intense heat) (Sahih Muslim)
>
> The hadith regarding the six rakats after Maghrib salah can be found
>   in Sunan Tirmizi where Saaiduna Abu Hurairah Radiallahu Anhu narrates
>   that the Prophet of Allah Sallallahu Alahi Wasalam said that the
>   performing of six rakats without indulging in any worldly affairs
>   would derive reward equivalent to twelve years nafl prayers. (Sunan
>   Tirmizi p.98 v.1)

**I would like to request more information on the subject.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Salaat al-Awaabeen (صلاة الأوابين) meaning the prayer of those who turn to Allah in repentance <sup>[(17:25)](https://quran.com/17/25)</sup>. It is the name of a supererogatory prayer (like tahajjud) which appears in various ahadith.

There are three main interpretations as to what it refers to:

- This is the same as Salat al-Duha, which is two or more rak`at offered before mid-day (see [How to pray Salatul Duha?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/44071)).

  > **صلاة الأوابين** حين ترمض الفصال
  >
  > Salat al-Awwabin is when the young camels feet feel the heat of the hot sand
  >
  > <sup>— [Sahih Muslim](https://sunnah.com/muslim/6/175)</sup>

  > وصاني خليلي بثلاث لست بتاركهن: أن لا أنام إلا على وتر، وأن لا أدع ركعتي الضحى فإنها **صلاة الأوابين**، وصيام ثلاثة أيام من كل شهر
  >
  > My friend (the Prophet ﷺ) instructed me to observe three things which I will never leave. Not sleeping without praying witr, the two rak`at of Duha for this is Salat al-Awwabin and fasting for three days every month.
  >
  > <sup>— [Sahih ibn Khuzaymah](https://al-maktaba.org/book/1446/1956)</sup>

  This view is supported by Sahih ahadith.
- It is the name of the prayer between maghrib and 'isha. These are six rak`at.

  > من صلى ما بين المغرب إلى صلاة العشاء، فإنها **صلاة الأوابين**
  >
  > Who prays between Maghrib and 'Isha, for it is Salat al-Awwabin
  >
  > <sup>— [Al-Zuhd wa al-Raqa'iq by Ibn Al-Mubarak](https://al-maktaba.org/book/13028/1291#p1)</sup>
- It refers to both of these collectively.

There are also other views.